# Python Script to move files depending on excel cells

Tags: python, excel, scripting

I want to copy files from one location to another. I have excel file which contains data. For example if the data is "Yes", I want to move it to another location, and if it is something else like "no" or "pending", do not copy it.

Here is what I have done so far. Please advise:

```
#Import Openpyxl and Shutil 
import openpyxl
import shutil

#Read a File (Excel File Must Be In Working Directory or Change Location)    
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('OfferDecision.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

for colOfCell in sheet['G2':'G158']:
    for cellObj in colOfCell:
       if sheet[cellObj.value] == "Yes":
            shutil.copytree(a\b, c)
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Are you getting an error? What is the error? Does it run without error but not do what you want?

Comment: So... what's the question?

Answer (score 2):

I have an excel file that looks like this

```
Y/N    File Name
Yes   LeoQ1.csv
No    LeoQ2.csv
Yes   LeoQ3.csv
No    LeoQ4.csv
```

here is the code that copies the files of column B to the desired directory named in variable dst. It copies the file based on the Yes/No in column A.

```
import openpyxl
import shutil
src = "C:\\Users\\martbar\\Desktop\\"
dst = "C:\\Users\\martbar\\Documents\\"
exFile = "C:\\Users\\martbar\\Desktop\\test.xlsx"

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(exFile)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
    if row[0].value == "Yes":
        file = src+row[1].value
        fileDst = dst+row[1].value
        shutil.copyfile(file, fileDst)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What should I do if I want to search and match file recursively?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Let me explain. I work at office where we have to review thousands of applications. What I am trying to do is copy directories and files within that directories to different location. It is difficult to do it manually. So I am trying to create a script. The excel file contains of meta data such as ID and Status. I am trying copy directories of IDs which has "Yes" on their status and do nothing with "No" status.